# Полный путь к папке на Objective-C

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, xcode

Доброе время суток, задача следующая: нужно выбрать папку и в лейбл вывести полный путь этой папки, куда нужно копать?

Comment: Откуда папки выбираете? Из App bundle или из файловой системы? Откуда конкретно?

Comment: В том то и дело что я не выбераю, я не знаю как это в принципе сделать ;(

Comment: Я написал ответ, но вообще-то ваш вопрос очень попадает в разряд вопросов типа "работа за автора", а такие вопросы тут не очень-то любят (в смысле любят закрывать).

Answer (score 5):

Слишком туманно вы ставите задачу, поэтому и ответ будет в общем виде:

Во-первых, напоминаю, что в iOS есть такая штука как Sandboxing (гугл в помощь), которая, если кратко, означает, что для любого вашего приложения доступ к файловой системе девайса ограничен несколькими директориями типа `Documents/` и `tmp/` (есть ещё несколько, но реально работать рекомендуется с `Documents` и `tmp/`), то есть вы можете получить доступ только к этим директориям, а к другим не можете.

Скорее всего вам нужно работать с `NSFileManager`.

Пробуйте такое (так как вы не знаете, что и откуда выводить, покажу для временной директории):

Чтобы посмотреть что находится в директории без прохода её поддиректорий:

```
NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSArray *directoryContents = [NSFileManager.defaultManager subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
NSLog(@"Содержимое директории без заглядывания в поддиректории: %@", directoryContents);
```

Чтобы посмотреть, что находится в директории с учётом всех поддиректорий, их поддиректорий итд:

```
NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSLog(@" %@", [NSFileManager.defaultManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil]);
NSLog(@"Содержимое директории с проходом по всем поддиректориям: %@", directoryContents);
```

---

**NSTemporaryDirectory()** - помогает получить путь до папки `tmp/` вашего приложения.
А вот способ получить путь до папки **Documents/** вашего приложения:

```
NSString *pathToDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSLog(@"Путь к директории Documents вашего приложения: %@", pathToDocumentsDirectory);
```

---

Используя методы выше вы получаете массивы содержащие внутренности директории в виде строк: путь к папкам и файлам, которые в этой директории находятся.

Потом вы используете что-нибудь вроде цикла

```
for (NSString *elementPath in directoryContents) {
    NSLog(@"Очередной элемент (путь к файлу или папку) лежащий в директории path: %@", elementPath);
    / Здесь вы можете взять этот elementPath и вывести его куда-нибудь в свой UI интерфейс.
}
```

---

Советую вам найти на русском языке документацию к классу [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/).

Там есть методы для создания файлов:

```
Creating and Deleting Items

– createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:
– createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:
– createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:
– removeItemAtURL:error:
– removeItemAtPath:error:
– replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:
– trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:
```

Методы для проверки существования файлов или директорий:

```
Determining Access to Files

– fileExistsAtPath:
– fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:
– isReadableFileAtPath:
– isWritableFileAtPath:
– isExecutableFileAtPath:
– isDeletableFileAtPath:
```

И **самая интересная для вас группа методов для работы с содержимым директорий**. О двух из них я уже упомянул с примерами выше.

```
Discovering Directory Contents

– contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:
– contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:
– enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:
– enumeratorAtPath:
– mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:
– subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:
– subpathsAtPath:
```

---

В этой же документации к `NSFileManager` также описывается ещё один способ прохода по содержимому директории (смотрите там описание метода enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:. Вот пример оттуда, который проходит по директории, по всем внутренностям и при это игнорирует находящуюся в ней папку extras и всё её содержимое:

```
-(void)scanURLIgnoringExtras:(NSURL *)directoryToScan
{
    // Create a local file manager instance
    NSFileManager *localFileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    // Enumerate the directory (specified elsewhere in your code)
    // Request the two properties the method uses, name and isDirectory
    // Ignore hidden files
    // The errorHandler: parameter is set to nil. Typically you'd want to present a panel
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnumerator = [localFileManager enumeratorAtURL:directoryToScan includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey,nil] options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles errorHandler:nil];

    // An array to store the all the enumerated file names in
    NSMutableArray *theArray=[NSMutableArray array];

    // Enumerate the dirEnumerator results, each value is stored in allURLs
    for (NSURL *theURL in dirEnumerator) {
        // Retrieve the file name. From NSURLNameKey, cached during the enumeration.
        NSString *fileName;

        [theURL getResourceValue:&fileName forKey:NSURLNameKey error:NULL];

        // Retrieve whether a directory. From NSURLIsDirectoryKey, also
        // cached during the enumeration.
        NSNumber *isDirectory;
        [theURL getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL];

        // Ignore files under the _extras directory
        if (([fileName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_extras"]==NSOrderedSame) &&
            ([isDirectory boolValue]==YES))
        {
            [dirEnumerator skipDescendants];
        }
        else
        {
            // Add full path for non directories
            if ([isDirectory boolValue]==NO)
                [theArray addObject:theURL];
        }
    }
    // Do something with the path URLs.
    NSLog(@"theArray - %@",theArray);
}
```

---

Того, что я написал, более, чем достаточно. Включайте разум и всё должно получиться.